# In Qt5, how can i make a window that floats on top of everything?

Tags: c++, qt, notifications

I want a window to show on top of all existing windows
It should also display on all workspaces if you have a multiple workspace system.

A typical application for this is showing a notification.

Answer (score 1):

The demo program included in `Qt` distribution features a `Widget/Window flags` application.

This application show you how to use the different `Qt::WindowFlags` for `QWidget::setWindowFlags` function. It also demonstrates the different types of widget, including `Qt::ToolTip`.

A `Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint` flag exists to set the widget on top of eveything. There is however no indication for the behaviour with multiple desktop (probably because this is not a function available on all systems).

Comment: i'll have a look into that

Comment: well, with a standard window, if i change X11 workspace, it stays on the old. i'd love to have it always stay on the selected workspace, kinda like chromes/chromiums notifications do